# Automatically add non-Google Calendar invites in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

In Google Calendar, I have "Events from Gmail - Add Automatically" and "Automatically add invitations to my calendar - Yes". And yet, it seems that when someone sends me an invitation from not-Gmail (Outlook, for instance), then that doesn't happen.

Instead, I get an invite with an "Add to calendar" link at the bottom - but it doesn't get added unless I click that.

The problem is I'm so used to working with other Google Calendar users that I forget to click this link, and as a result, have missed a couple of things.

Is there a way to make it behave consistently with non-Google Calendar sources?